# ConfigMap with multiple destination folders

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My configMap file:

```
kind: ConfigMap 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
  name: config
data:
  config.xml: |
{{ .Files.Get "configuration/config.tpl" | indent 4 }}
  control1.xml: |
{{ .Files.Get "controlsets/control1.tpl" | indent 4 }}
  control2.xml: |
{{ .Files.Get "controlsets/control2.tpl" | indent 4 }}
```

How do I achieve that *config.xml* will be mounted to *configuration* folder and both control files to *controlsets* folder? Thank you for answer.

**EDIT:**
I solved issue but I think it can be done more dynamically.

configMap file stays the same.

volumeMounts part of deployment file:

```
volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /app/Configuration/config.xml
      subPath: config.xml
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /app/Controlsets/control1.xml
      subPath: control1.xml
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /app/Controlsets/control2.xml
      subPath: control2.xml
```

How would I achieve that all files which are in *controlsets* folder go into
*/app/Controlsets* folder and all files in *configuration* go to */app/Configuration* folder with script? Now I have to change yaml files for each config file I add. It would be nice If just write relations between folders and the rest is done by helm.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by traversing the folder.

**config.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Values.test.name }}
  labels:
    {{- range $k, $v := $.Values.test.labels}}
    {{ $k }}: {{ $v }}
    {{- end }}
data:
  {{- range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  "configuration/**" }}
  {{ (base $path) | trimSuffix ".tpl" }}.xml: |-
    {{ $.Files.Get $path | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```

**deployemnt.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: config-volume
              name: /app/Configuration
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: {{ $.Values.test.name }}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. I am new in helm charts. I did found solution (look my edit) but it is hardcoded for each file. It would be nice if I could write this logic in script.

Comment: You can mount the directory directly (look my edit)